# MS-Word-2010 cross reference of math. equations gap in paragraph

Tags: hyperlink, ms-word, cross-reference

I created a word document in version 2010. The mathematical equations are described by a number and written as follow.

```
          a= b/c               Eq.4.5

 Now if I use equation number in text to refer towards   a= b/c               Eq.4.5 with hyperlink then whole 
 equation is appearing in text (as shown before in mid of sentence).
```

After reading into several blogs, I redefine number with 'insert bookmark' option by only selecting number 'Eq.4.5'.

```
 Now if I use this bookmark in text to refer towards                Eq.4.5 with hyperlink then a gap is    
 appearing in text (as shown before in mid of sentence).
```

Please can someone guide me how to remove this gap from text? as manually I can remove it but in print or update of document it appears again and again. If I switch on 'Show/Hide' option, it look like with small arrows as follows.

```
    --> --> --> -->  Eq.4.5
```

Comment: It appears the bookmark counts the 'tab's before the number too. (As that is what the small arrows indicate. Try remaking the bookmark and making sure it only has the number selected (by for instance using shift + arrow key right)

Comment: You can also make the bookmarks shown within MS Word by selecting the Option.
File -> Options -> Advanced -> Show bookmarks

Comment: @viperbone; Thanks.Is there a way to change the color of these used bookmarks automatically, when used as cross-reference hyperlink in text?

Comment: @Umar: No, not that I'm aware of to change the bookmarks color in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the bookmark counts the 'tab's before the number too. (As that is what the small arrows indicate.)

Try remaking the bookmark and making sure you **only** have the number selected (by for instance using shift + right arrow key)

Comment: Is there a way to change the color of these used bookmarks automatically, when used as cross-reference hyperlink in text?

Comment: You mean like how links online often turn a different colour when visited before?

Comment: like for instance in above case when we refer to 'Eq. 4.5' in text, so 'Eq. 4.5' should appear in different color. More like when links are mentioned in different documents with blue color.

Comment: A bookmark normally uses the same styling as the original text,so you can change it though that. If you only wish to style the number in the bookmark itself, you'll need to style your bookmarks specifically.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using a table and a caption. The table is needed to separate the equation from the caption.

1. Make a table with invisible lines that is 3 columns wide and 1 row.
2. Edit the properties of the table so that the total table width is 100% width, and the columns are each 10%, 80%, and 10% width.
3. Set the Valign to the cells to be middle.
4. Add the equation to the center cell of the table.
5. Click on the right cell of the table and add a caption. Since the equation is in a separate table cell, the equation will not be considered part of the caption. If the caption is added to the table itself instead of appearing in the cell, then just highlight the caption and drag it into the cell.
6. Center the equation in its cell and it will be centered in the page.
7. Right-align the equation number and it will be right-aligned to the page